# Relative interior and epigraph of convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

Consider a Banach space $X$ and a non empty convex set $C \subseteq X$ and let $f : C \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex functional.

1. Does $C$ have a non-empty relative interior? If no, what necessary and sufficient conditions should $C$ satisfy for it to have a non-empty relative interior?
2. Does the epigraph of $f$ over $C$ defined as $[f,C] := \{ (r,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times X : r \ge f(x) \}$ have a non-empty relative interior? If it does not necessarily have a relative interior, what necessary and sufficient conditions should $f$ or $C$ satisfy for it to have a relative interior? If it exists, is the relative interior precisely equal to the set $\{ (r,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times X : r > f(x) \}$, and if yes, how does one prove it?

Comment: I've been thinking about your questions, and here are some notes. 1. You can find an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389419/convex-analysis-relative-interior-in-finite-and-infinite-dimension) to show that relative interiors need not exist in infinite dimensions. 2. If $\operatorname{epi} f$ has non-empty interior for some $f$, then so must $C$ (by projecting onto $X$). 3. Without $f$ being continuous (or lsc), the (relative) interior of $\operatorname{epi} f$ can be empty even when $C = X$ (e.g. take $f = \phi^2$, where $\phi$ is a discontinuous linear functional).

Comment: Even with (lower-semi)continuity, I can't seem to quite show that $\operatorname{ri}C\neq\emptyset\implies\operatorname{ri}\operatorname{epi}f\neq\emptyset$. I seem to need $\operatorname{aff} C$ to be closed (and the completeness of $X$ seems necessary here too). I don't have a counterexample to back this up though.

Comment: I do notice that your proposed form for the relative interior of $\operatorname{epi} f$ is definitely not correct though, even in finite-dimensions. For example, take $f(x) = -\sqrt{1 - x^2}$, and take the point $(1, 2)$ in the epigraph. The epigraph has an interior, so the affine hull will be $\Bbb{R}^2$, and the point $(1, 2)$ satisfies $f(1) < 2$, but moving in the direction $(1, 0)$ will immediately cause you to exit the epigraph. You may want to restrict the $x$ coordinate to lie in $\operatorname{ri} C$. I *suspect* that if $\operatorname{epi} f$ has a relative interior, this will be it.

Comment: Thank you for your notes. They are helpful.

Comment: @TheoBendit Note that (see e.g. Mordukhovich and Nam's book on Convex Analysis) one possible definition of relative interior in infinite-dimensional spaces is the interior relative to the **closed** affine hull.